# How fast is "too fast" for Uric stones?

Tags: weight-loss, uric-acid, length-of-time, calculi-stones

I've been [reading](https://www.livestrong.com/article/548516-does-losing-weight-affect-your-kidneys/) that rapid weight loss could cause Uric stones?

How fast is rapid weight loss? 5 pounds per month?

Answer (score 3):

The only weight loss method I've heard that increases the risk of *kidney stones* is bariatric surgery ([PubMed, 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4382441/)).

Here's a recommendation to prevent *gallstones ([NIDDK.gov, pdf](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/-/media/Files/Weight-Management/DietingandGallstones2002.pdf)):*

> Depending on your starting weight, experts recommend losing about
>   **1/2 to 2 pounds per week.**

Comment: *"Bariatric surgery is the only method for weight loss"*  Huh?  What about dieting?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you tried to say and edited for clarity.